# Converting php [] to array() syntax in multiple files

Tags: php, arrays

I'd like to create a (temporary) version of my web app that supports PHP < 5.4, for which I need to convert all my short array syntax to the long one.

There's plenty of "old to new" scripts, but the only "new to old" one seems to be this — https://github.com/slang800/php-array-syntax-converter, however when I tried running it, it gave me the following error:

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to processTree() must be
an instance of Pharborist\TopNode, instance of Pharborist\RootNode
given
```

Hopefully, someone has had a similar experience and could point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: It's an issue with the dependencies, checking [the issues on github](https://github.com/grom358/pharborist/issues/175) tells you that, simply change `TopNode` to `RootNode`, or use the more generic `NamespaceNode` type-hint

Comment: Right, that fixed the error, but it doesn't do anything to my code. I suppose there are other issues with the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I'd simply write my own script, so you don't have to wait for a fix to be written for the script you're using now. It's really not that hard to work out what to replace, really: It's all occurrences of this pattern `/\[[^]]*\]/` that are part of an expression, other than `$var[$idx]` (accessing an index of an array, or pushing onto an array: `$var[] =`).

Off the top of my head, I'd write a script that just does this, basically:

```
$pattern = '/(=>?|,|\[|\()\s*\[([^]]+)\](?!\s*=)/';
$script = file_get_contents('path/to/file.php');
$rewritten = preg_replace(
    $pattern,
    '$1 array($2)',
    $script
);
//only AFTER you've checked the output, of course!
file_put_contents('path/to/file.php', $rewritten);
```

Note that this regex isn't finished just yet: it can't cope with nested arrays like:

```
$x = [ $y[1] => [1, 2, 3]];
```

But [Play around with it here](https://eval.in/234730), until you can get it to work. It might be worth while using `preg_match_all` with a different pattern, matching the entire expression containing nested arrays, and replace what needs replacing separately. That'd make your life a lot easier, I do think